# How do I implement and load new posts using the 'pull to refresh' Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, wordpress-rest-api

Am building an Android app using **Ionic 3** and **wordpress**  **REST API**

am trying to `console.log` the pull to refresh functionality using the code

```
 doRefresh(refresher) {
    console.log('Begin async operation', refresher);

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Async operation has ended');
      refresher.complete();
    }, 2000);
  }
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are right about using the refresher component. The doRefresh method is invoked by the view, we fetch the data and once done, we call complete() method on refresher object.

**.ts**

```
  import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
    items: any;
      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public storage: Storage) {
        this.doRefresh();
      }
        doRefresh(refresher){
            this.storage.get('myStore').then((data) => {
              this.items = data;

              if(refresher)
                 refresher.complete();
            }); 
        }
```

**HTML**

```
  <ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
    <ion-refresher-content 
      pullingText="Pull to refresh"
      pullingIcon="arrow-dropdown"
      refreshingSpinner="circles"
      refreshingText="..fetching">
    </ion-refresher-content>
  </ion-refresher>
```

Comment: Am new in Ionic so I have added my service in the edit. Please take a look.

Comment: Ionic 3 no longer uses Http. Fix your service to use the new HttpClient.

Comment: I dont have `myStore` who does it mean?